# hadoop compression program got stuck while executing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, compression

I am facing a problem in execution of a compression program in hadoop. The code that I am trying is the following:

```
public class StreamCompressor {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String codecClassname = args[0];
    Class<?> codecClass = Class.forName(codecClassname);
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    CompressionCodec codec = (CompressionCodec);
    ReflectionUtils.newInstance(codecClass, conf);
    CompressionOutputStream out = codec.createOutputStream(System.out);
    IOUtils.copyBytes(System.in, out, 4096, false);
    out.finish();
  }
}
```

While executing this code, it does not run; it is showing only a blinking cursor. Here is a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjkDe.png).

It got stuck after giving running command.